# Swift function with a closure parameter seen as error type inside Unit Testing Module

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to write Unit tests for my Article Model. I have added the model as a test target.

I am able to access class functions without closure parameters in it but when I try to use a function with a closure, here's what Xcode's autocompletion gave

[image]

The full function prototype of 'fetchArticles' looks likes this:

```
class func fetchArticles(referringTile:Tile,completion:(articles:[Article])->(Void),
failure:(error:NSError)->(Void))
```

I've also tried declaring the function as 'public' but it didn't work.

Comment: This is just a hunch, but you might want to try taking out the parameter names inside the closure parameters. That is, `..., completion: [Article] -> Void, ...`. Swift has problems with named single-element tuples.

Comment: Also, that method would be more consistent with other APIs if it took a single completion handler that had `([Article], NSError?)` as the input.